# For some reason synchronous replication does not work (everything works asynchronously)

Tags: postgresql

For some reason synchronous replication does not work (everything works asynchronously)

**Master settings:**
wal_level = replica
fsync = on
synchronous_commit = on
max_wal_senders = 10
wal_keep_segments = 512
synchronous_standby_names = 'ANY 1 (post122, post124)'

**Slave 1 settings:**
wal_level = replica
fsync = on
synchronous_commit = on
max_wal_senders = 10
wal_keep_segments = 512
primary_conninfo = 'host=10.128.241.123 port=5432 user=replica application_name=app124'
primary_slot_name = 'slot124'
hot_standby = on

**Slave 2 settings:**
wal_level = replica
fsync = on
synchronous_commit = on
max_wal_senders = 10
wal_keep_segments = 512
primary_conninfo = 'host=10.128.241.123 port=5432 user=replica application_name=app122'
primary_slot_name = 'slot122'
hot_standby = on

If execute sql statement

```
SELECT pg_wal_lsn_diff(pg_current_wal_lsn(), s.sent_lsn) AS send_byte_lag, pg_wal_lsn_diff(s.sent_lsn,s.replay_lsn) AS replay_byte_lag, * FROM pg_stat_replication s;
```

you can see that sync_state = async for all nodes.

```
+-----------------+-------------------+-------+------------+--------------------+----------------------+------------------+-------------------+---------------+--------------------------------+----------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------------------------+
| "SEND_BYTE_LAG" | "REPLAY_BYTE_LAG" | "PID" | "USESYSID" |     "USENAME"      |  "APPLICATION_NAME"  |  "CLIENT_ADDR"   | "CLIENT_HOSTNAME" | "CLIENT_PORT" |        "BACKEND_START"         | "BACKEND_XMIN" |   "STATE"   |   "SENT_LSN"   |  "WRITE_LSN"   |  "FLUSH_LSN"   |  "REPLAY_LSN"  |    "WRITE_LAG"    |    "FLUSH_LAG"    |    "REPLAY_LAG"    | "SYNC_PRIORITY" | "SYNC_STATE" |          "REPLY_TIME"          |
+-----------------+-------------------+-------+------------+--------------------+----------------------+------------------+-------------------+---------------+--------------------------------+----------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------------------------+
|                 |                   |       |            |                    |                      |                  |                   |               |                                |                |             |                |                |                |                |                   |                   |                    |                 |              |                                |
| "0"             | "0"               | 14914 | 69296      | "replica"          | "walreceiver"        | "10.128.241.122" | NULL              | 60010         | "2020-07-27 11:49:35.202751+03 | NULL           | "streaming" | "BA5/D20002D0" | "BA5/D20002D0" | "BA5/D20002D0" | "BA5/D20002D0" | NULL              | NULL              | NULL               | 0               | "async"      | "2020-08-11 11:05:22.398199+03 |
|                 |                   |       |            |                    |                      |                  |                   |               |                                |                |             |                |                |                |                |                   |                   |                    |                 |              |                                |
| "0"             | "0"               | 14913 | 69296      | "replica"          | "walreceiver"        | "10.128.241.124" | NULL              | 47916         | "2020-07-27 11:49:35.202262+03 | NULL           | "streaming" | "BA5/D20002D0" | "BA5/D20002D0" | "BA5/D20002D0" | "BA5/D20002D0" | NULL              | NULL              | NULL               | 0               | "async"      | "2020-08-11 11:05:21.838096+03 |
|                 |                   |       |            |                    |                      |                  |                   |               |                                |                |             |                |                |                |                |                   |                   |                    |                 |              |                                |
| "0"             | NULL              | 14952 | 85885      | "streaming_barman" | "barman_receive_wal" | "10.128.241.223" | NULL              | 53304         | "2020-07-27 11:50:01.795733+03 | NULL           | "streaming" | "BA5/D20002D0" | "BA5/D20002D0" | "BA5/D2000000" | NULL           | "00:00:07.658259" | "65:31:39.378476" | "359:15:13.971633" | 0               | "async"      | "2020-08-11 11:05:15.781336+03 |
+-----------------+-------------------+-------+------------+--------------------+----------------------+------------------+-------------------+---------------+--------------------------------+----------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------------------------+
```

And such a moment is also suspicious, in the slave settings `application_name = app124` is specified and in select `application_name = walreceiver` as if application_name is not recognized.

What can be done to make synchronous replication work?

Comment: You want `synchronous_commit = remote_apply` in the configuration of the primary https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-SYNCHRONOUS-COMMIT

Comment: I don't understand. It's question?  I want synchronous replication.  The documentation indicates several levels of synchrony and according to my logic, synchronous replication should work with any value of synchronous_commit. Just synchronous_commit = remote_apply should be faster than ON. Isn't it?

Comment: "*I want synchronous replication.*" - then you have to use `remote_apply` or `remote_write` as described in the link from my comment and description in the chapter [Synchronous Replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/warm-standby.html#SYNCHRONOUS-REPLICATION)

Comment: I'll try it now on the server, but I still don't understand why it doesn't work with ON. Because the documentation, just below "26.2.8.1. Basic Configuration" says that "synchronous_commit must also be set to on, but since this is the default value, typically no change is required."

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `synchronous_commit = on` is enough for synchronous replication.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: but it won't appear to be "synchronous" if you query the standby immediately after committing something on the primary. That setting only makes the primary wait for the WAL to be accepted, not full replayed. The "synchronous" character only reflects the "transport" of the WAL, not the visibility of the transaction on the standby. If something should be visible on the standby immediately after the COMMIT on the primary has finished (which is what many people expect with "synchronous"), `remote_apply` or `remote_write` is required.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I understand; the default setting is "synchronous with respect to avoiding data loss" rather than "synchronous with respect to visibility on the standby". OP has a different problem though: the `sync_state` in `pg_stat_replication` is `async`. That has nothing to do with the visibility of changes on the standby.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a typo.

You used `application_name=app124` and `application_name=app122` in `primary_conninfo` on the standbys, but `synchronous_standby_names = 'ANY 1 (post122, post124)'`.

Answer (score 0):

I done it :)

1. There was a typo. Thank @LaurenzAlbe. Synchronous_standby_names on master used application_name (post122, post124) and slave used primary_conninfo (app122, app124).
   Made on master
   synchronous_standby_names = 'FIRST 1 (app124, app122, barman_receive_wal)'

But it didn't help because

2. Postgresql.auto.conf had another primary_conninfo on both slaves.
   Removed through ALTER SYSTEM RESET ALL

Synchronous replication is working.

Now such settings (*synchronous_commit decided to set to remote_write*)

**Master:**
wal_level = replica
fsync = on
synchronous_commit = **remote_write**
max_wal_senders = 10
wal_keep_segments = 512
synchronous_standby_names = 'FIRST 1 (**app124, app122**, barman_receive_wal)'

**Slave 1:**
wal_level = replica
fsync = on
synchronous_commit = remote_write
max_wal_senders = 10
wal_keep_segments = 512
primary_conninfo = 'host=10.128.241.123 port=5432 user=replica application_name=app124'
primary_slot_name = 'slot124'
hot_standby = on

**Slave 2:**
wal_level = replica
fsync = on
synchronous_commit = remote_write
max_wal_senders = 10
wal_keep_segments = 512
primary_conninfo = 'host=10.128.241.123 port=5432 user=replica application_name=app122'
primary_slot_name = 'slot122'
hot_standby = on

Thank to all!

```
+-----------------+-------------------+-------+------------+--------------------+----------------------+------------------+-------------------+---------------+--------------------------------+----------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------------------------+
| "SEND_BYTE_LAG" | "REPLAY_BYTE_LAG" | "PID" | "USESYSID" |     "USENAME"      |  "APPLICATION_NAME"  |  "CLIENT_ADDR"   | "CLIENT_HOSTNAME" | "CLIENT_PORT" |        "BACKEND_START"         | "BACKEND_XMIN" |   "STATE"   |   "SENT_LSN"   |  "WRITE_LSN"   |  "FLUSH_LSN"   |  "REPLAY_LSN"  |   "WRITE_LAG"    |   "FLUSH_LAG"    |   "REPLAY_LAG"    | "SYNC_PRIORITY" | "SYNC_STATE" |          "REPLY_TIME"          |
+-----------------+-------------------+-------+------------+--------------------+----------------------+------------------+-------------------+---------------+--------------------------------+----------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------------------------+
|                 |                   |       |            |                    |                      |                  |                   |               |                                |                |             |                |                |                |                |                  |                  |                   |                 |              |                                |
| "0"             | "0"               | 38269 | 69296      | "replica"          | "app124"             | "10.128.241.124" | NULL              | 46536         | "2020-08-11 15:39:26.610345+03 | NULL           | "streaming" | "BA5/D7010708" | "BA5/D7010708" | "BA5/D7010708" | "BA5/D7010708" | NULL             | NULL             | NULL              | 1               | "sync"       | "2020-08-11 15:57:01.972806+03 |
|                 |                   |       |            |                    |                      |                  |                   |               |                                |                |             |                |                |                |                |                  |                  |                   |                 |              |                                |
| "0"             | "0"               | 38270 | 69296      | "replica"          | "app122"             | "10.128.241.122" | NULL              | 58578         | "2020-08-11 15:39:26.626625+03 | NULL           | "streaming" | "BA5/D7010708" | "BA5/D7010708" | "BA5/D7010708" | "BA5/D7010708" | NULL             | NULL             | NULL              | 2               | "potential"  | "2020-08-11 15:57:01.97172+03" |
|                 |                   |       |            |                    |                      |                  |                   |               |                                |                |             |                |                |                |                |                  |                  |                   |                 |              |                                |
| "0"             | NULL              | 38311 | 85885      | "streaming_barman" | "barman_receive_wal" | "10.128.241.223" | NULL              | 50770         | "2020-08-11 15:40:02.10472+03" | NULL           | "streaming" | "BA5/D7010708" | "BA5/D7010708" | "BA5/D7010708" | NULL           | "00:00:00.00168" | "00:00:00.00168" | "00:16:59.671909" | 3               | "potential"  | "2020-08-11 15:57:01.789078+03 |
+-----------------+-------------------+-------+------------+--------------------+----------------------+------------------+-------------------+---------------+--------------------------------+----------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------------------------+
```